# Assign static IP in Ubuntu server 14.10

Tags: server, ip

Iam running Ubuntu Server 14.10 in Oracle VM VirtualBox.
Whenever i start the VirtualBox, it changes IP address.
To run putty or WinScp, i had to check everytime. Is there any way to assign a static IP so that i need not login to check IP everytime i start the VirtualBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check available NIC by typing "ifconfig -a"
Go to you /etc/network/interfaces file and edit according to the interface 
appeared after previous command or that you want to select.

auto **eth0**
iface **eth0** inet static
address **192.168.x.x**
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway **192.168.1.1**
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Change things that are in bold and enter below commands to restart networking -

sudo ifdown **eth0**
sudo ifup **eth0**

Comment: to what should the bold things be changed??

Comment: you must change it according to your network.